# Compound If statement generates Runtime Error

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

I have code that moves an email to a folder and mark it as read when I assign a category to the email.

The code actually works, in that it does what I want it to do, with the exception of throwing this error.
[image: Error]

When I debug it shows the following
[image: Debug]

```
Private WithEvents objInboxFolder As Outlook.Folder
Private WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items

'Process inbox mails
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInboxFolder = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objInboxItems = objInboxFolder.Items
End Sub

'Occurs when changing item
Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objTargetFolder As Outlook.Folder

    If TypeOf Item Is MailItem And Item.Categories <> "" Then
       Set objMail = Item

       'Move mails based on color category
       If InStr(objMail.Categories, "Personal") > 0 Then
          Set objTargetFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Personal")
          objMail.Move objTargetFolder
       Else
          objMail.UnRead = False
          objMail.Save
          Set objTargetFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("01 Actioned")
          objMail.Move objTargetFolder
       End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `If TypeOf Item Is MailItem And Item.Categories <> ""`.

VBA evaluates every term of a Boolean expression before combining them to get the final result.  It does not check `TypeOf Item Is MailItem` and only continue if `Item` is a `MailItem`.  If `Item` is not a `MailItem`, `Item.Categories` will fail.

Try:

```
If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
  If Item.Categories <> ""
    . . . .
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Hi @tonydellimore,  Thanks for your answer it does make sense to me.  Unfotunately I get the same error.  I used the following after yours gave the same error but still same issue        If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
       Set objMail = Item
       If objMail.Categories <> "" Then

Comment: Where is it stopping?  ` Set objMail = Item` or `objMail.Categories <> ""`?

Comment: A different possibility is `Item`.  `Item` is an Outlook Object.  When you use an Outlook keyword as a variable name, it can fail because the interpreter is confused. However, I often see `Item` used as a variable name in working code.  Try replacing `Item` with `MyItem` or `ItemCrnt` or other name of your choice.